# Efficiently join tables by intervals (tricky)

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i have 2 tables that looks like this

```
___A___       _____B____
id | a        id | s | e
1  | 5        1  | 4 | 6
2  | 4        2  | 2 | 7
3  | 3        3  | 3 | 4
              4  | 1 | 5
```

Table A and has approximately 1,500,000 and 200,000 rows respectively. I want to join the tables by the smallest interval that A.a is within in.

This is my query but it is very slow

```
select A.a,
       B.s,
       B.e
  from A
  join B
    on A.a > B.s
   and A.a < B.e
   and (B.e - B.s) = (
       select min(B.e - B.s)
         from B
        where A.a > B.s
          and A.a < B.e
   )
```

The subquery is used to make sure that we use the smallest interval. Is there any way to make this run faster?

Thanks

Comment: 1. How many intervals will one 'a'typically fit inside? 2. What indexing do you have? 3. Did you choose not to use a range type and if so why not?

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS()` variant *could* be more efficient (but it still needs the correct indices, obviously)

Comment: Post the execution plan of your current query, please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a postgresql expert but you can try using a CTE:

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT MIN(B.e - B.s) AS MinInterval
FROM #A AS A
     INNER JOIN #B AS B ON A.a > B.s AND A.a < B.e) , B AS 

(SELECT A.a
     , B.s
     , B.e
FROM #A AS A
     JOIN #B AS B ON A.a > B.s AND A.a < B.e
                     AND (B.e - B.s) = (SELECT MinInterval FROM A))
                 SELECT * FROM B;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT EXISTS()` version can sometimes avoid an aggregating subquery:

```
SELECT a.a,
       b.s,
       b.e
  FROM AAAA a
  JOIN BBBB b
    ON a.a > b.s
   AND a.a < b.e
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM BBBB nx
        WHERE a.a > nx.s
         AND a.a < nx.e
         AND (nx.e - nx.s) < (b.e - b.s)
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [RANK() window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) makes this relatively straightforward:

```
SELECT ranked.id, ranked.val, ranked.start, ranked.end
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.val,
        b.start,
        b.end,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY (b.end - b.start) ASC, b.id ASC) AS match_rank
    FROM a
    JOIN b
      ON a.val BETWEEN b.start AND b.end
) ranked
WHERE ranked.match_rank = 1
```

You find all matches, then for each match you assign it a rank value based on how small `b`'s range is.  The smaller the range, the better (using `b.id` as a tiebreaker to prevent duplicates).  Then we only keep the best match for each `a.id`.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8dff7/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try the group by version:

```
select  A.a
      , B.s
      , B.e
from    A
join    B on A.a > B.s and     A.a < B.e
group by A.a
      , B.s
      , B.e
      , B.e - B.s
having (B.e - B.s) = min(B.e - B.s)
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this can result in duplicates if there's two ranges of the same size that match `a`'s value.  Example, `a.a = 5`, `b.s = 3, b.e = 6` and `b.s = 4, b.e = 7`

Comment: @Mr.Llama : the same as in the original query (and mine)